# Can a non-admin user sniff network traffic?

Tags: networking, windows, linux, wireshark

Is it possible for a non-administrator/non-root user in Windows/Linux to sniff network traffic?

With no preinstalled third-party tools.
(The user can install third-party tools, but without admin rights).

Answer (score 2):

They can sniff data from the local machine without admin privileges. If they want to sniff the whole network, they need to be an administrator to set the Wi-Fi card to monitor mode.

Also, in some cases, the administrator can disable sniffing with Wireshark.

If you are not an admin user, you should consider using the portable version of Wireshark, so you don't have to install it.

Comment: The portable version of Wireshark still needs the Npcap driver to be installed upfront, doesn't it?

Comment: Nice. Doesn't Wireshark need drivers to capture packets?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can use tools like wireshark, Mitmf, xersoplit, etc to sniff the data

Comment: But they need high privileges to install them, don't they?